# pass method with arguments in other method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm interesting how to pass method with arguments in ruby. I need to implement something like command pattern with flexible function setting. Example => lambda functions in C#.

Comment: I can't understand your question, can you please provide us an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby `lambda` functions are defined as follows:

```
  a.lambda{ puts "Hello"}
  a.call #=> Hello

  a = lambda{|str| puts str }
  a.call("Hello world !!!") #=> Hello world !!!

  a = lambda{|*args| puts args.join(' ')}
  a.call("Hello", "World") #=> Hello World
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the command pattern the way you do most things in Ruby: with a block.

```
class Soldier

  def initialize(&block)
    @command = block
  end
  def action
    @command.call if @command
  end

end

s = Soldier.new do #the block
  line = "We are drill machines, drill machines feel no pain"
  2.times{ puts line }
  puts line.upcase
end

puts "Action:"
s.action
```

Comment: it's also possible to use yield construction there?

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically invoke methods along with their argument lists.  Below is only one of the ways

```
class Foo
  def foo(what)
    puts what
  end
end

Foo.new.send(:what, "something")  # ==> "something"
```

Comment: OK, that's interesting point. but how can I use for passing code to another method and the call it from there? Could you provide some simple example.